# String in array showing up as undefined, despite being console.log-ed successfully a few lines earlier

Tags: javascript, for-loop, parse-platform

In the for loop below, when I `console.log` `searchTermsList[i]` the first time (`console.log('searchTermsList[i] is:' + searchTermsList[i]);`), it works correctly and prints out the respective string.

However, when I do it again later in the code (`console.log('the searchTermsList[i] Im about to use for the query is:' + searchTermsList[i]);`), it prints out that it's undefined. Both console.logs are within the same loop, so why isn't the 2nd one able to find the value?

```
for (var i = 0; (i < top3List.length) && (i < searchTermsList.length); i++){

        console.log('searchTermsList[i] is:' + searchTermsList[i]);
        console.log('top3List[i] is:' + top3List[i]);

        var MCI_Results = Parse.Object.extend("MCI_Results");
        var MCI_Results_Comparison_Query = new Parse.Query(MCI_Results);

        // Compare respective items' MCI_Results array to eBay results (top3List[i])
        MCI_Results_Comparison_Query.equalTo('parent', user);
        MCI_Results_Comparison_Query.contains('searchTerm', searchTermsList[i]);
        MCI_Results_Comparison_Query.containsAll('Results', top3List[i]);

        MCI_Results_Comparison_Query.find()
          .then(function(results) {

            // No new items, Results and top3List[i] are identical                     
            if (results.length > 0) {
              console.log('done updating channel');
            }

            // New items found, Results and top3List[i] don't match.
            else {
              console.log('no matching MCI_Results, lets push some new shit');

              // Find MCI_Results object for specific item
              var MCI_Results_Update_Query = new Parse.Query(MCI_Results);
              MCI_Results_Update_Query.equalTo('parent', user);
              console.log('the searchTermsList[i] Im about to use for the query is:' + searchTermsList[i]);
              MCI_Results_Update_Query.contains('searchTerm', searchTermsList[i]);

              // Update MCI_Results with new top3List eBay results
              MCI_Results_Update_Query.find()
                .then(function(results) {
                  console.log('totally just updated the MCI_Results, NBD');
                })
                .then(function() {
                  // Check for high priority MC items
                });
            }

          });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is a mutable variable. `i++` will change `i` to point to a different index by the time that function is called.

You'll need to create a new variable in a new scope, possibly using an immediately-invoked anonymous function, and not change it.

An example:

```
var makeBadAdders = function(n) {
    var adders = []
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        adders[i] = function(x) {
            // Closes over a mutable variable.
            // Function will use the most up-to-date value of i.
            return i + x;
        }
    return adders
}
var badAdders = makeBadAdders(3);
console.log(badAdders[1](1)); // 4
console.log(badAdders[2](1)); // Also 4

var makeAdders = function(n) {
    var adders = []
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        adders[i] = makeAdder(i);
    return adders
}
var makeAdder = function(i) {
    // Closes over an effectively immutable variable (i).
    return function(x) {
        return x + i;
    }
}

var goodAdders = makeAdders(3);
console.log(goodAdders[1](1)); // 2
```

Note that you could write `makeAdder` inline like so:

```
adders[i] = (function(i) {
    return x + i
})(i)
```

(This shadows the outer, mutable `i`.)

But usually, it's better to just avoid mutable variables and use something like `forEach` instead. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Ah I see. Would you mind giving me an example of how this would be done in this scenario? I'm not very familiar with immediately-invoked anonymous functions.